# Using Chrome Developer Tools, how do I tell the cause of "Unexpected response code: 401"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, http, httpresponse, google-chrome-devtools

I'm debugging my ASP.NET MVC 3 web app using Google Chrome Developer Tools, and for some reason, the error "Unexpected response code: 401" gets logged every time a page is loaded. I don't have a clue for which request DevTools is receiving this response, though; I've even inspected the `Network`pane in DevTools, without seeing any such response from the server. Also, the app appears to work just fine, I can't see the 401 response having any actual effect.

How can I tell in DevTools what causes this response from the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the network pane open, reload the page. Each row in the pane represents a different resource - you can sort the status column by clicking on it. Once you've found your 401, click on the page resource (the left-hand column) to see the request/response details.

From the Wikipedia page *[List of HTTP status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error)*:

> Similar to 403 Forbidden, but specifically for use when authentication
>   is possible but has failed or not yet been provided.[2] The response
>   must include a WWW-Authenticate header field containing a challenge
>   applicable to the requested resource

So your root problem is that you either haven't provided authentication details or the details provided weren't accepted.

Comment: Like I mention in my question, I've inspected the Network pane (and sorted on Status), but the 401 response is nowhere to be seen. This is an intranet application though, which automatically logs me in through AD, so it could be an initial hiccup during authentication (although I see I'm successfully authenticated).

Comment: Where is the error getting logged? Have you tried Firebug (for a second opinion)?

Comment: It gets logged in the console. I'll consider Firebug as well.

Comment: Anyway, even though it didn't help me in this case, I figure your answer does explain how to proceed in the general case (when Chrome actually logs the 401 in the Network pane). Therefore I might as well accept your answer.